# Problemas con reputación

Tags: discusión

Mi reputación desde que llegué al sitio (Meta esSO, en esSO no he participado aún) ha estado en 101 a pesar de tener preguntas y respuestas con varios upvotes. Las medallas sí están apareciendo poco a poco según las condiciones establecidas...

¿Me estoy perdiendo de algo, es un bug o será así durante la beta?

Comment: El funcionamiento que ves es algo historico. Originalmente existia un solo [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), pero habia todo tipo de problemas porque cuando te daban un voto negativo bajaba el puntaje. Pero en meta el voto negativo tiene un significado diferente que en los sitios Q&A. Ademas que tantos Sitios tuvieran un solo Meta era complicado, porque se mezclaban preguntas especificas de SO, con preguntas de como mejorar los sitios SE en general. Entonces se crearon los Metas de todos los sitios, y ahi no cambia la reputacion, para que te sientas comodo preguntando.

Comment: Eso si, si posteas en [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) tu reputacion si cambia, porque es un sitio como si fuera SO, pero sobre la construccion de los sitios SE y como deben funcionar en general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hola JhonAlx he visto tu perfil y noto que aun tienes la reputación por defecto, efectivamente puedo ver que tienes preguntas con votos positivo pero las preguntas realizadas en:
https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/
NO influyen en la reputación. Te lo comento porque es algo que yo también he notado dado que es un sub-foro de StackOverflow:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu perfil en `StackOverflow en Español`, aún no tiene preguntas ni respuestas:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/670/jhonalx

Comment: Entonces ¿Rep en esSO = Rep en Meta esSO?

Comment: @JhonAlx asi es, la reputación es la misma, pero solo ganas reputación desde esSO, no en Meta

Comment: @JhonAlx Citado de [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): *"Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow en español (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges."* ("Los votos en meta no afectan tu reputación; tu reputación en meta es la misma que tu reputación en Stack Overflow en español (sincronizada cada hora), pero ganas medallas distintas.")

Comment: Listo, ya quedaron resueltas mis dudas. Gracias a todos :)